# Build up multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm struggling building up a multidimesional array from database to display data in a calendar... Basically, I have a table, where there always is a date, a description and a link to the event. I then want to display that data in a calendar and found a little php programmed one, that looks okay.

Now this PHP code takes a `$events` variable to display events, the structure of the array has to be the following:

```
$events = [
  '2020-04-05' => [
    'text' => "An event for the 5 july 2015",
    'href' => "http://example.com/link/to/event"
  ],
  '2020-04-23' => [
    'text' => "An event for the 23 july 2015",
    'href' => "/path/to/event"
  ],
];
```

Now as I didn't work too much with multidimensional arrays in PHP (except the ones received as database result), I tried building this array up, but I can't seem to be able to..

What I get from my db is an array, that looks like the following:

```
array (


 0 => 
  array (
    'ID' => '1',
    'link' => 'example.com/link',
    'description' => 'that\'s a description',
    'eventDate' => '2020-04-07 01:04:25',
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'ID' => '6',
    'link' => 'example.com/link',
    'description' => 'that\'s a description',
    'eventDate' => '2020-04-15 00:00:00',
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'ID' => '7',
    'link' => 'example.com/link',
    'description' => 'that\'s a description',
    'eventDate' => '2020-04-16 07:24:11',
  ),
  3 => 
  array (
    'ID' => '8',
    'link' => 'example.com/link',
    'description' => 'that\'s a description',
    'eventDate' => '2020-04-26 07:07:10',
  ),
)
```

So I thought of a `foreach` over that array, create a new array for the events before and build it up by something like `$events[$foreachVar["date"] = "test"` in order to at least get that index, but not even that helps..

Can anybody help me out with that or is there a better way to do it (a better calendar, that integrates the database better?)

PS: If it minds, I'm using Fat Free Framework as a little microframework.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: In your database result you have multiple events on the same day. Since  a PHP array can only have one element with a given key (the date in your case), how do you want to deal with that. If you could show the expected output for your given database result that would make it a lot easier to answer the question.

Comment: @Nick sorry, for some reason something went wrong when updating the database (on_update current timestamp was set, even though I didn't want to), I corrected the data now.

The output of the database is the second array I posted.. What I need is a format, like in the example, where the `$events` variable is built up, so `arrayResult["eventDate"]` would be the key for the new array, `link` would need to be the `href` of the `$events` array and `description` would be `text` of the array..

Comment: Note: The better way is to create the desired array using the SQL database query.
PDO has the modes PDO::FETCH_UNIQUE and PDO::FETCH_GROUP for these tasks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate over your database result, getting the `date` portion of `eventDate` as the output array key and selecting the `description` and `link` elements for the output:

```
$events = array();
foreach ($data as $event) {
    $events[date('Y-m-d', strtotime($event['eventDate']))] = array(
        'text' => $event['description'],
        'href' => $event['link']
    );
}
var_export($events);
```

Output (for your sample data):

```
array (
  '2020-04-07' => 
  array (
    'text' => 'that\'s a description',
    'href' => 'example.com/link',
  ),
  '2020-04-15' => 
  array (
    'text' => 'that\'s a description',
    'href' => 'example.com/link',
  ),
  '2020-04-16' => 
  array (
    'text' => 'that\'s a description',
    'href' => 'example.com/link',
  ),
  '2020-04-26' => 
  array (
    'text' => 'that\'s a description',
    'href' => 'example.com/link',
  ),
)
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/tGnLa)

Note I've been a bit paranoid with the date, wanting to allow for any format in the database. If it's definitely in `yyyy-mm-dd HH:ii:ss` form, you can just use `substr($event['eventDate'], 0, 10)` to extract the date portion i.e.

```
foreach ($data as $event) {
    $events[substr($event['eventDate'], 0, 10)] = array(
        'text' => $event['description'],
        'href' => $event['link']
    );
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$events = [];
foreach($array as $key => $value){
  $events[$value['date']] = $value;  
}
```

print $events and you will get idea.
ask me if you need more help.